# Is it possible to set the different gravity on 2 objects in the same scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine

If Physics.gravity works for all rigidbodies in the scene
Does it have another way to set the different gravity of Ground1 and Ground2?

Answer (score 2):

Yes!

Gravity is by default handled by each Rigidbody in the scene, but you can disable the default gravity by doing `Rigidbody.useGravity = false;`

This means that you can deactivate the default gravity, and then apply a force to the object (simulating the gravity) the way you want:

```
RigidBody.AddForce(Vector.down, ForceMode.Acceleration);
```

Remember that you can simply multiply `Physics.gravity` by the number you want, or even change the direction doing something like:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class GravityDirectionChanger : MonoBehaviour
{    
    public enum GravityDirection
    {
        Up, Down, Forward, Backward, None
    }
    public static Dictionary<GravityDirection, Vector3> gravityDirectionDict = new Dictionary<GravityDirection, Vector3>
    {
        { GravityDirection.Up, Vector3.up },
        { GravityDirection.Down, Vector3.down },
        { GravityDirection.Forward, Vector3.forward },
        { GravityDirection.Backward, Vector3.forward * -1 },
        { GravityDirection.None, Vector3.zero }
    };

    [SerializeField] private GravityDirection gravityDirection = GravityDirection.None;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(gravityDirectionDict[gravityDirection], ForceMode.Acceleration);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no other way to set Physics.gravity to affect different objects in different ways.  You could roll your own limited physics system in Unity if you just want very simplistic physics (or a full custom physics system if you're insane). Alternatively, you can add forces to the objects that you wish to behave differently.

For objects that you wish to be affected by gravity differently, you will need to apply an additional force in the direction of gravity to increase the effect of gravity or against the direction of gravity to decrease the effect of gravity.  You will also need to use ForceMode.Acceleration to ensure that the force is applied without regard to mass.

See: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html

And: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.Acceleration.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, i think you can change the gravity scale of those two objects, say 2 and then physics.gravity for those two objects will be 2*original physics.gravity.